# Multireference field types in C#

Tags: fieldtype

I know that `Treelist` and `Checklist` fields are of Type `MultilistField` in C#, but I need to know the C# types for the following field types:

- `TreelistEx`
- `Multilist`
- `MultilistWithSearch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the C# types of the `List Type` field:

**Checklist**:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField
```

**Droplist**:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ValueLookupField
```

**Grouped Droplink:**

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.GroupedDroplinkField
```

**Grouped Droplist**:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.GroupedDroplistField
```

**Multilist**:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField
```

**Multilist with Search**:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField
```

**Name Lookup Value List**:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.NameValueListField
```

**Name Value List**:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.NameValueListField
```

**Treelist**:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField
```

**TreelistEx**:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField
```

Answer (score 0):

To use these fields in code, you have to add reference to Sitecore.Kernel dll and then you can use it.
For example

```
MultilistField itemsInMultiList = dataSourceItem.Fields["SelctedTags"];
```